# Is it possible to add label field into device via Data Converter?

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I would like to fill label and description fields without any manual work.
Or what is the best way for TB to fill those fields?
[Label & Description in device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InJHU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the rulechain.

You should have in you rulechain tab the Root rule chain, add a script transformation node after the message filter one (you need to connect the two nodes with an Entity created tag if you want it to be done on every device).[image: rule chain]

to access the label and the description in the node you need "msg.additionalInfo.description" and "msg.label" [image: script]

add the nodes to he existing root rule chain, and add an originator filter for device if you only want this to be done on devices

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the Label via Data Converter ("deviceLabel" or "assetLabel" key). Description is not supported, yet.
Support was added in version 3.3.2:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/reference/releases/#v332-november-11-2021

```
// Result object with device/asset attributes/telemetry data
var result = {
// Use deviceName and deviceType or assetName and assetType, but not both.
   deviceName: 'Name',
   deviceType: "Type",
   deviceLabel: "Label",
   attributes: {},
   telemetry: {}
};
```